# Java if (string=="0") check doesn't work

Tags: java, syntax

I want to make a program that copies strings into a vector until the `hold` string is set to a certain value, at which point the program should print out the elements of the array.

I'm not sure how the `in.nextline()` function works, so it could be that I'm not erasing previous entries from `hold`, or is it that my `if(hold=="0")` check is simply not valid java?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class startingPoint 
{
    public static void main(String roark[])
    {
        String hold;
        boolean finished=false;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Vector<String> vec = new Vector<String>();
        while(finished==false){
        System.out.print("Enter the string you'd like to save, or enter 0 to print out saved strings\n");
        hold=in.nextLine();
        if(hold=="0"){
            for(int looper=0;looper<vec.size();looper++){
                System.out.print(vec.get(looper));
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            finished=true;
        }else{
            vec.add(hold);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: This would have to be the most frequently asked question on S.O. please delete it!

Comment: @John3136 my understanding is that leaving dups increases the chance of finding different phrasing of the same old question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use equals method:

```
if("0".equals(hold){
```

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't come up with the search query that SO wanted.